# Having .NET applications "remember" preferences, etc?

Tags: c#, .net

This is sort of a "newbie" question, but I was wondering what the best way is to have .NET applications store user-configured data between runs.

For example, if I wanted to create a list of preferences for my application, what would be the best way to store those preferences, so that they take effect for the next time I run the application? What file type should I store it as? Where should I store it? I want the application to take care of all of that, so the user doesn't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you writing a web application or a Windows application?  The answer may vary based on the environment, but in general you have several options for storing preferences:

- Database table (SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, or SQL Server Express are good options)
- XML or formatted text file
- Application configuration file (app.config or web.config)
- Windows Registry

Again, it depends on the environment, but these are a few options.

Comment: Agreed 100%, and probably in that order too.  A database would be ideal, but I wouldn't add one only for saving settings.  A XML file or INI would be my second choice, followed by App/Web.config, and I would avoid the registry.  I would only use the app config if the values wouldn't change too often.  The .NET Settings for windows apps referenced by @Anthony Shaw might be an option, but I've never used them...

Comment: For winforms it would be user.config. app.config is for application-scoped settings and is read-only.

Answer (score 7):

I'm assuming you're referring to a Windows Application?

There is a Settings class built into the application that you can use. The only thing that you'll want to take care with is on application upgrades, but you can check if the settings need to be upgraded and run the appropriate method

Here is an article that walks through creating these, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25zf0ze8.aspx

Then when the application is upgraded (say with OneClick Deployment) you need to call this block of code, or else your settings will be reverted to default

```
if (Properties.Settings.Default.CallUpgrade)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.Upgrade();
    Properties.Settings.Default.Reload(); // to activate the settings
    Properties.Settings.Default.CallUpgrade = false;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();// to save the new value of CallUpgrade            
}
```

Comment: +1 For a typical winforms app this is the most sensible solution. Why reinvent the wheel? Properties.Settings works.

Answer (score 1):

VS Projects have profile based preferences for application in the project properties, you could make use of that.

Answer (score 1):

One common way to do this is via the [Windows registry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.aspx). Applications usually create their own folders in the registry and store there data such as language, layout, etc. which will be remembered in subsequent runs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your Visual Studio **project settings** with **User domain** settuped.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a65txexh%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) is a short example how to do that.

**EDIT**

This is valid for desktop application only.